Is $E \cup \{\infty\}$ necessarily homeomorphic to some unit sphere?
Let $E$ be a normed vector space. We define a topological space $\tilde{E}$ by adjoining a new point $\infty$ to $E$ with a neighbourhood basis of $\infty$ given by complements of bounded sets.
Note that this is not the same as the one-point compactification of $E$ since we allow $E$ to be infinite-dimensional.
Question: Is $\tilde{E}$ necessarily homeomorphic to the unit sphere of some normed vector space $F$?
If $E$ is finite-dimensional, this is clearly true. The interesting part of the question is what happens for infinite-dimensional $E$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The answer
Yes, $\tilde{E}$ is always homeomorphic to the unit ball of some $F$.
Let $F = \mathbb{R} \oplus_2 E$. Let $S$ be the unit sphere of $F$. Consider the maps
$$
f: S \to \tilde{E}, \begin{array}{l} \begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \infty \end{array}
$$
and
$$
g: \tilde{E} \to S, \begin{array}{l} v \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\|v\|^2 - 1}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\ \infty \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \end{array}
$$
They are simply stereographic projection and its inverse.
We will now show the following things:

$f$ is continuous

$g$ is continuous

$f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_{\tilde{E}}$

$g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_S$


This shows that $f$ is a homeomorphism between $S$ and $\tilde{E}$.
@MoisheKohan's comment brought the idea of using stereographic projection to my attention.
$f$ is continuous
Clearly, $f$ is continuous at any $\begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. Now, for $\begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} \in S$, we have $t^2 + \|v\|^2 = 1$ and hence $\|v\| = \sqrt{1 - t^2}$. This implies that as $t \to 1$, we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left\| \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \right\|
& = & \left| \frac{1}{1 - t} \right| \cdot \|v\| \\
& = & \left| \frac{1}{1 - t} \right| \cdot \sqrt{1 - t^2} \\
& = & \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - t)^2} \cdot (1 - t^2)} \\
& = & \sqrt{\frac{1 + t}{1 - t}} \\
& \to & \infty \\
\end{array}
$$
This implies that $f$ is also continuous at $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. Hence $f$ is continuous everywhere.
$g$ is continuous
Clearly, $g$ is continuous at any $v \neq \infty$. As $\|v\| \to \infty$, it is clear that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\|v\|^2 - 1}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot  v \\ \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows that $g$ is also continuous at $\infty$. Hence $g$ is continuous everywhere.
$f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_{\tilde{E}}$
Now take any $v \neq \infty$. Then we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(f \circ g)(v)
& = & f(g(v)) \\
& = & f\left(\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\|v\|^2 - 1}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\|v\|^2 - 1}{\|v\|^2 + 1}} \cdot \frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot v \\
& = & \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1}\right)} \cdot \frac{2}{\|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot v \\
& = & v \\
\end{array}
$$
We also have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(f \circ g)(\infty)
& = & f(g(\infty)) \\
& = & f\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right) \\
& = & \infty \\
\end{array}
$$
This shows that $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_{\tilde{E}}$.
$g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_S$
Take any $\begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ in $S$, i.e. with $t^2 + \|v\|^2 = 1$. Then we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(g \circ f)\left(\begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)
& = & g\left(f\left(\begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\right) \\
& = & g\left(\frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v\right) \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\left\|\frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v\right\|^2 - 1}{\left\|\frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v\right\|^2 + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\left\|\frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v\right\|^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 \|v\|^2 - 1}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 \|v\|^2 + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 \|v\|^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 (1 - t^2) - 1}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 (1 - t^2) + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - t}\right)^2 (1 - t^2) + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\frac{1 + t}{1 - t} - 1}{\frac{1 + t}{1 - t} + 1} \\ \frac{2}{\frac{1 + t}{1 - t} + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - t} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\left(\frac{2t}{1 - t}\right)}{\left(\frac{2}{1 - t}\right)} \\ \frac{2}{2} \cdot v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{array}
$$
Also, we have
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
(g \circ f)\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)
& = & g\left(f\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\right) \\
& = & g(\infty) \\
& = & \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{array}
$$
This shows that $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_S$.
$\tag*{$\square$}$
